# Entity Relationship Diagram: How to create a Yelp-kind of app with not just one price-range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, entity-relationship, erd

Im new to Rails and I'm in the middle of sketching up an ERD for my new app. A Yelp-sort of app, where a Client is sorted by price.

So I want one Client to have many priceranges - One Client can both have pricerange $ and Pricerange $$$$ for example. The priceranges are:
$ - $$ - $$$ - $$$$ - $$$$$

How would this look in a table? Would I create a table called PriceRange with Range1, Range2, Range3, Range4, Range5 to be booleans?

Doesn't the PriceRange-table need any foreign/primary keys?

```
PriceRange
Range1 (Boolean)
Range2 (Boolean)
Range3 (Boolean)
Range4 (Boolean)
Range5 (Boolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look, I'm Brazilian and I'm not very knowledgeable about yelp applications. I do not quite know what it is, but from what I saw, they are systems to assess/measure/evaluate (perhaps the translation is wrong here for you) things, in this case, companies, right?

Following this logic, let's think...

By the description of your problem (context), you have clients (companies), and they can have price ranges, correct? If:

- A price interval is represented by textual names, such as "$", "$$",
  and so on,
- and the same price range may have (numeric) values for different companies,
- And the same price range (type) can be (or not) assigned to different
  companies,

Then here is what we have:

[image]

By decomposing this conceptual model, you would end up with three tables:

- Companies
- Price Ranges
- Price Ranges from Companies

The primary keys of Company and Price Ranges will be passed to Price Ranges from Companies as foreign keys. You can use them as a composite primary key, or use a surrogate key. If using a surrogate key, you will permit/allow a company to have the same kind of price range more than once, which I believe is not the case.

Let's look at another situation, if things are simpler as:

- If there is no need to store prices,
- and an company may have or not one or more price ranges represented by "$", "$$", and so on,

Then here is what we have:

[image]

Similarly, we'll have the same 3 tables. Likewise, you still must pass the primary keys of Companies and Price Ranges to Price Ranges from Companies as foreign keys.

> So I want one Client to have many priceranges - One Client can both
>   have pricerange $ and Pricerange $$$$ for example

Notice how N-N relationships allow us to create optional relationships between entities. This will allow a company to have zero, one, two, (etc.) or all price ranges defined. Again, so that is not allowed a company to have a price range more than once, set the foreign keys as composite primary key in Price Ranges from Companies.

If you have any questions or anything I explained has nothing to do with your context, please do not hesitate to comment.

### EDIT

> Is the Price ranges from companies what is called a Joint table?

Yes. There are also other terms used, some in different areas of computer science, such as Link Table, or Intermediate Table.

Actually we do not have a table here in the diagram, but an entity. In the Conceptual Model there are no tables, but entities and relationships. Be careful with this terminology when developing the Conceptual Model, or else you may get confused (I say this from experience).

However, yes, once decomposed, we will have a table from this relationship. When decomposed, N-N relationships  will always become tables, no exception. Differently, 1-1 and 1-N (or N-1) relationships do not become tables. These tables with these special names (Join/Link/Intermediate Tables) serves to associate records from different tables, hence the name.

> And is it necessary to have a column called Price Range Id? I mean
>   what is it there for?

At where? If you say at the Price Ranges entity, it is rather necessary. Must We  not identify records in a table in some way? Here I set what is called a [Surrogate Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). If on the other hand, you have a column with unique values for each record in the table, you can also use this column. I highly recommend that you consider the use of surrogate keys. Read the link I gave you.

In the Conceptual Model, we have to define the properties and also the primary keys. During the phase of the conceptual model, natural attributes of entities can become primary keys if you so desire. In this case, we have what is called a [Natural Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key).

If on the other hand you refer to Price Ranges from Companies entity, so the question is another ("And is it necessary to have a column called Price Range Id?"). Here we have a table with two columns, as I told you. The two are foreign keys. You need it so you can relate rows from the two tables... I think you were not referring to that, is not it? If so, no problem, you can comment and ask more questions. I do not care to answer. To be honest, I did not quite understand your question.

### EDIT 2

> So that Company 28 can be identified in the Price Ranges (for instance
>   ID 40) Which would make it easier to call out the price ranges it has?

Maybe my English is not very good, but it seems to me that you have a beginner's doubt/question in relation to the concept of tables and relationships between them. If not that, I apologize because maybe I did not understand. But let's see...

The tables in a database have rows / records. Each line has its own data. Even with this, each line / record needs to be differentiated and identified somehow. That is why we attach to each line an identifier, known as the primary key ([this](http://databases.about.com/cs/administration/g/primarykey.htm), and [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-primary-key.htm)). In summary, the primary key is how we identify, differentiate, separate and organize different records.

Even if all records have different values, you must select a field (column) that represents the primary key of the table. By obligation, every record MUST have a primary key. Although you can choose which field is a primary key, you are allowed to choose one or more fields to serve as the primary key. When this happens, that is, when more than one field participates/serves as the primary key, we have a table with something called [Composite Primary Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key). Similarly, it has the ability to identify records. Note that, because of that, primary key values must be unique, otherwise you may have 2 identical records.

This is the basic concept so that we can relate tables to each other, in case, records/rows of tables together. If we have a Company identified by the ID 28 (a line/record), and we want to relate it to a Price Range identified by the ID 40, then we need to store somewhere that relationship (28 <--> 40). This is where the role of intermediate/link/join tables comes in (but only to relationships N-N! For 1-N or N-1 relationships it works similarly, but not identical).

> My original question was whether it was necessary, and why a company
>   ID had to link up with a price range ID at all.

With this table storing records which relates to other records (for their primary keys), we can perform a [SQL join operation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) (If you have questions about this, see [this image](http://guiadba.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/visual_sql_joins_orig.jpg)). Depending on how you perform this operation, you'll get:

- All companies that have Price Ranges.
- All companies that do not have Price Ranges.
- All the Price Ranges of a given company.
- All companies that have or not a X Price Range.
- All price ranges that are given or not to companies.
- ...

Anyway, you get all this because of the established relationship.

> If it could just be taken out and then the table of price ranges would
>   only involve Pricerange1-5.

This sentence I did not understand. What should be taken out? Could you please explain this sentence better?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's a very nice and well-written answer Loa! I'm leaning toward the latter model. So two questions: Is the Price ranges from companies what is called a Joint table? And is it necessary to have a column called Price Range Id? I mean what is it there for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I took a look into the surrogate key-description and if we say that one Company is to be linked up to one auto-incrementing value from the Price Range ID, I think I understand why it makes sense.

So that Company 28 can be identified in the Price Ranges (for instance ID 40) Which would make it easier to call out the price ranges it has? 

My original question was whether it was necessary, and why a company ID had to link up with a price range ID at all. If it could just be taken out and then the table of price ranges would only involve Pricerange1-5. Makes sense? :)

Comment: @Snegl, take a look above.

Comment: That's a supreme and very solid answer Loa! Thank you so much! I now have a better understanding of why the pricerange-table needs a primary key too! Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: @Snegl, you're welcome. I'm glad to help. In return, if not ask you a lot, try to join the community. Do like me, when you know and can, please, help others. Remember the most important thing: we are here to exchange knowledge. Good luck, and have good studies. :)

Comment: Thanks. Almost 50% of when I try to google an answer to something, I end up on StackOverflow, so I'll definitely try and contribute back to the community, when I feel my knowledge is great enough to help others :)